# using vmkfstools to move a snapshot

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx

I am trying to move a snapshot from an esxi 5.0 vm to another datastore, but when I tried to use the datastore tools I got the following error, "error caused by file" with a path to the vdmk file. So I am to use vmkfstools to move the snapshot but can't find how to move the snapsot. I found how to migrate a virtualdisk:

```
vmkfstools --server 10.21.49.14 -i '[Datastore] examplevm/examplevm.vmdk' '[Datastore 2] newexamplevm/newexamplevm.vmdk' -d thin
```

I have searched other forums and but haven't found any examples. I am not sure that the above command would move the snapshot. Has anyone used vmkfstools to move a snapshot? If so please provide an example

Comment: What you are doing doesn't really make sense.  A snapshot is linked to a vmdk.  The snapshot without the source vmdk is meaningless.

Comment: I agree, the reason I was trying to use vmkfstools is that when I try to move the vmdk with the datastore tools I get "error cause by file" with a path to the vmdk.

Answer (score 0):

So hopefully this will help someone else who has seen the same issue where using the datastore snapshot tool to copy. The issue was that we had the file system formatted as reiserfs, when we reformatted it as ext4 the we were able to use the datastore tools successfully.